# How to create Excel 2003 (.XLS) file with password protection without Excel installed with c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, passwords

In C#, how can I create a PASSWORD PROTECTED (user has to enter password to OPEN the file at all) .XLS file without having Excel installed (therefore not Interop)? NPOI and ExcelLibrary look promising (because they are free!), but I cannot seem to find anywhere whether or not they actually support password protection.  I cannot use EPPlus since it only deals with .XSLX file types, not my required .XLS.

Also, I would like to use an array to populate the data, not cell by cell. Here's what I did to accomplish this when I used Interop in the past, which was infinitely faster than cell by cell method:

```
object[,] data = new object[length, ColumnHeaders.Count];
...
dynamic rg = excelApp.Sheets[p].Range[excelApp.Sheets[p].Cells[top, left], excelApp.Sheets[p].Cells[bottom, right]];
rg.Value = data;
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting question... I would have thought that the answer was no, but I'm keen to see if you get any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Export code

```
 public void ExportNewPatientsToExcel()
    {
        logger.Info("New Patients :: export to excel");
        string fileDirectory = string.Empty;

        if (Session[Constants.SESSION_FILE_DIRECTORY] != null)
            fileDirectory = Session[Constants.SESSION_FILE_DIRECTORY].ToString();
        else
        {
            logger.Error("New Patients::File Cache folder is not set.");
            Response.Redirect(Constants.PAGE_ERROR);
        }

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        try
        {           
            string xsltFileName = Context.Server.MapPath(Constants.NEW_PATIENTS_XSLT_FILE_NAME);
            PatientCollection patientCollection = PatientBAO.GetNewPatients(ShowAllPatient);

            if (patientCollection.Count > 0 && patientCollection != null)
            {
                string fileName = PatientBAO.GenerateNewPatientsAsExcel(fileDirectory, xsltFileName, patientCollection);
                logger.Info("New Patients Excel version saved name :" + fileName);
                string fileNamePart = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                fileNamePart = fileNamePart.Substring(fileNamePart.IndexOf("_") + 1);//added to remove session id from file name

                context.Items.Add(Constants.ENABLE_CACHE_SZ, Constants.ENABLE_CACHE);
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileNamePart);
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.TransmitFile(fileName);                
            }
            else
            {
                ShowPopUp(Resources.Patient.RecordNotFoundToExportExcel);
                logger.Error("New patients data not found for export to excel.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            logger.ErrorException("Error occured while export patient details to excel.", exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Password part im working on.

Comment: let me know when you figure out the password part

Answer (score 0):

Check the souce code sample from:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1831409.aspx

You can also populate the data by a dataset, not cell by cell.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  it does appear EasyXLS is a trial, so you'd have to buy the product though.